# How do I add an inputed phrase to a dictionary?

Tags: c, file, dictionary

So I've been trying to do a dictionary using .txt and .dat files, to save the dictionary and then re-open the information when needed, this includes the word and its definition
Eg: Orange -> It's an Orange fruit

but I just cannot find a way to pass the Definition (Def) to this text file while using structs.

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  


struct palavra{
  char nome[46];
  char definicao[400];
  int tamanho;
};

void add_word(){
  char pal[46],def[400];
  int cont =0;
  struct palavra input;
  
  
  printf("Entre com a palavra:");
  scanf("%s", input.nome);

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input.nome); i++) {  
        if(pal[i] != ' ')  
            cont++;  
    }  
  //printf("%d", cont);
  printf("Entre com a definição:");
  scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input.definicao);

  
 
  
  FILE* dicionario;
  dicionario = fopen("dicionario.dat","w");
  
  fwrite (&input, sizeof(struct palavra), 1, dicionario);
  fclose (dicionario);


  dicionario = fopen ("dicionario.dat", "r");
    if (dicionario == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
  while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct palavra), 1, dicionario))
        printf ("palavra =%s def =%s tamanho= %d\n", input.nome,
        input.definicao, input.tamanho);
}

  

int main(void) {
  add_word();
  
  
}
```

Note, I'll add the expected output(edited image) as well as the input I'm getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec4si.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0phMh.png)

Comment: "*a way to pass the Definition (Def) to this text file while using structs*". It's nor clear what that means. What does it mean to "pass" something to a file. Please describe in terms of the input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: I wanted to be able to add/write (words;definition) structs to a file and later identify a definition by a word searched, like, if i wanted to search for the word apple, it would search the file and give back the definition of apple.

Comment: I know that is what you want to do. But what specific problem do you have? What error or incorrect behaviour do you get with your code? As already mentioned, please provide the input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Oh I got it, just added some pictures to try to get it a little more clear, take a look there

Comment: Please do not post text as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.